# Inequality with sides and angles in a triangle

Tags: inequality, triangles

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle. Show that
> $$ 60^o \le \frac{aA+bB+cC}{a+b+c} \le 90^o$$
> where $A$ is the measure in degrees of the angle corresponding to the vertex $A$ and $a$ the side opposite to it ($B$, $b$, $C$ and $c$ are defined similarly).

I saw this problem in a Facebook group and couldn't figure out the solution. It was a long time ago, so there is no way I can find that post again (only took a screenshot of the problem).

I have no idea where to start. My thoughts about the problem:

1. $a+b+c$ is the perimeter of the triangle.
2. The quantity $\frac{aA+bB+cC}{a+b+c}$ is the weighted average angle with sides as weights.
3. The formula is obvious for an equilateral triangle.
4. Since $\frac{aA+bB+cC}{a+b+c}=60^o$ is obtained for an equilateral triangle, I was thinking using Lagrange multipliers method with the Law of Cosines, Law of Sines and $A+B+C=180^0$ has constraints but the computations seem complicated.

Any idea?

Comment: I think you mean triangle instead of circle in the first point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the right inequality. Notice that $a,b,c$ satisfy $a+b+c>2a, a+b+c>2b, a+b+c>2c$ due to the triangle inequality. Multiply these inequalities respectively with $\alpha, \beta,\gamma$ $$(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)\cdot (a+b+c)>2\cdot(a\alpha+b\beta+c\gamma)\iff90^\circ=\frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}2>\frac{a\alpha+b\beta+c\gamma}{a+b+c}$$

For the second one, suppose wlog $a\geqslant b\geqslant c$. This implies, as [it is well-known](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookI/propI18.html), that $ \alpha\geqslant \beta\geqslant \gamma$ so you can use Chebyshev's inequality as follows $$\frac{a\alpha+b\beta+c\gamma}3\geqslant \frac{(a+b+c)}3\cdot\frac{(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)}3\iff \frac{a\alpha+b\beta+c\gamma}{a+b+c}\geqslant \frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}3=60^\circ$$

Comment: Now this is a famous inequality, I remeber seeing this in Zdravko inequality book

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I've just checked it and you are of course right! I also remembered this inequality, but was not sure where I had seen it 

Comment: Dr Mathva I had forgotten the proof ,remebered it when i saw your post,btw how do you get those 'emojis' in chat ?

Comment: I use a Mac, with which I can go to `Edit`, and then press `Emojis and Symbols`

Comment: Oh is this the only emoji that is compatible,i see you using this emoji frequently

Comment: Yes, it's really accurate when showing what my face looks like after some comments :)